# How to implement Google Cloud Message in android

Tags: android

How to implement Google Cloud Message in an Android application?

Comment: When you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html), what did you learn?

Comment: Best tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't really give you the code as each application has it's own unique features.
But I can tell you what are the best/common sources.

First of all - read the official documentation (it's really step by step) - [Here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Second, Here's a nice tutorial with code to implement, [check this one out](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139)

Hope it will help you.